# Windows XP Scheduled Task Parameters

Tags: parameters, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I have searched around the web for an answer to this question to no avail... I have an application that creates Scheduled Tasks via the C++ `ITask` Interface ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381311(v=vs.85).aspx ).

It works correctly but I recently added the SetParameters function to handle an instance of scheduling a perl script to run.  For instance, the command is:
`C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe C:\Compare.pl -I C:\input.txt`

I was initially able to make this as part of the task to run.  However, it failed due to appending some extra quotation marks on the command.  So I would get:
`"C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe C:\Compare.pl -I C:\input.txt"`

in the run section of the scheduled task properties.  Since there are tons of these servers, manually removing it is out of the question.

This could easily be fixed by creating a batch script and scheduling it (which we are currently doing).  However, I want to fix it right.  Thus, my use of the SetParameters command.

My Question:  Is SetParameters supported in Windows XP/Server 2003?  and if so, how can I verify that they have been set?  I have looked in the scheduled task properties section and even tried `schtasks /Query /FO LIST /V` and I still don't see the parameters.  All I get is the task to run property to be `C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe`  Also, NOTE I am aware of the support for Windows server 2008 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in my application. I can confirm that parameters are viewable in Windows XP. They show up like this:

C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe C:\Compare.pl -I C:\input.txt

In the task text box when you view properties.